# How to check if object is empty or filled with empty prop

Tags: javascript, object

how to find if object is empty even if it have property.

e.g.

```
// this is EMPTY in my case, dispite it have prop
// because prop is empty anyway
var obj2 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": []}};
```

**What did I try:**

```
function isEmpty(data) {
   return !_.isEmpty(data);
}

var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": []}};

console.log(isEmpty(obj1)); //true
console.log(isEmpty(obj2)); // false but should be true
```

**Question:**

Is there some nice way how to check if object is empty without knowing name of every possible properties?

**What i found but may be not the best solution:**

This is prolly solution for my problem but it's way to complicated in bigger object.

```
var isEmpty = true;
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {            
        // check if prop is array or 
        // object and go deeper again
        // else check for prop.length
        // set isEmpty to false if > 0
    }
}
```

Is there some other way which is more human?

Comment: That's basically it. You'll have to recursively traverse the object graph looking for properties with values.

Comment: There is no other way. What you wrote is the solution. For bigger objects you just have to make the method to call itself.

Answer (score 1):

A function like this will help you to quickly check if the object has at least one non-empty property. This function will take any object and check every (deep/nested) property to determine if the obj is empty. We stop at the first occurrence of a "non-empty" property, to save time.

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    var res = true;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (! obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { continue; }
        var type = typeof obj[prop];

        switch (type){
            case "object":
                res = isEmpty(obj[prop]);
                break;

            case "boolean":
            case "number":
                res = false; // boolean cannot be "empty", also 0 is not empty
                break;

            case "string":
                res = ! obj[prop].length;
                break;

            case "undefined":
                res = true;
                break;

            default:
                res = !! obj[prop];
                break;
        }
        if (!res) {break;}
    }
    return res;
}

var obj1 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": [], "test": ""}};
var obj2 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": [], "test": "1"}};

alert( isEmpty(obj1) )
alert( isEmpty(obj2) )
```

However, this method is relatively slow (the `hasOwnProperty` check is the main bottle neck). If you need to do this check often, or have complex objects I would cache the results somehow. Possibly like this:

```
var _cache = {};
function isEmpty(obj) {
  // Try to get the result from the cache.
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  if (undefined !== _cache[json]) { 
    return _cache[json]; 
  }

  // here is the code from above...

  _cache[json] = res; // Add the result to the cache.
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(isEmpty(obj2)); // false but should be true
```

This is not true at all.

If

```
var obj2 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": []}};
```

then `obj2` actually is not *empty* at all, because of the `subProp`.

And then yes, you have to recurively traverse the object to check every property.

Comment: I mean in my case, not in general in programming :) I said it on top of my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a recursive function to traverse the object.  See below:

```
var obj1 = {};  //empty
var obj2 = {"oneProp": {"subProp": []}}; //empty
var obj3 = {"a": {"b": [], c: "not empty"}}; //not empty
var obj4 = {"very": {"deeply": { "nested": {"object": [] } } } } //empty

function isEmptyRecurse(obj) {
    return _.isEmpty(obj) || ( _.isObject(obj) && _.every(_.values(obj),isEmptyRecurse) )
}


console.log(isEmptyRecurse(obj1)); //true
console.log(isEmptyRecurse(obj2)); //true
console.log(isEmptyRecurse(obj3)); //false
console.log(isEmptyRecurse(obj4)); //true
```